# Word distance algorithm for OCR

Tags: algorithm, ocr, levenshtein-distance, hamming-distance

I am working with an OCR output and I'm searching for special words inside it.

As the output is not clean, I look for elements that match my inputs according to a word distance lower than a specific threshold.

However, I feel that the Levenshtein distance or the Hamming distance are not the best way, as the OCR always seem to make the same mistakes: I for 1, 0 for O, Q for O... and these "classic" mistakes seem to be less important than "A for K" for instance. As a result, these distances do not care of the amount of differences of the appearances of the characters (low / high).

Is there any word distance algorithm that was made specifically for OCR that I can use that would better fit my case? Or should I implement my custom word distance empirically according to the visual differences of characters?

Comment: If you ever read the tesseract source you will see it special handles cases alot of those

Comment: are you using tesseract ocr on 64 bits JVM ?

Comment: @manu No, I use ABBYY FineReader.

Comment: then you're working with a trial version

Comment: @manu no it's not trial. Why asking? Is there some hidden stuff in paid version I should know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Levenshtein distance allows you to specify different costs for every substitution pair (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Possible_modifications, fifth item). So you can tune it to your needs by giving more or less emphasis to the common mistakes.

Comment: I'm going to try that with a cost between 0 and 1 for each levenshtein action between the two strings depending on char values. That should give me a distance in double.

Comment: Have you solve this issue? Let me know you haven't. I work for ABBYY and ready to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I you want a custom cost function for letter mismatch you could look at the Needleman–Wunsch algorithm (NW)

- Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm
- OCR paper related to the NW-algorithm http://oro.open.ac.uk/20855/1/paper-15.pdf

Comment: This is a good read. Using Needleman-Wunsch to find taxonomic names in a first pass with two different OCR outputs. Then using these names to find these hard words on the second pass in all documents. It can work.